# How to publish a ROS msg on Linux terminal

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ros msg as follows

int32 x
int32 y
char type

I want to give values to them on linux terminal. Something like this:

> > rostopic pub /topic message -- 2 3 'x'

But it doesn't work. I am using ROS Diamond.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218818/how-to-publish-a-ros-msg-on-linux-terminal/) by [Hossein](https://answers.ros.org/users/19386/hossein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-10-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS wiki gives this as an answer example.

```
$ rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

Depending on your message type you can simply follow the pattern given above; in which case you won't need `--` in your command. Instead wrap the message data in single quotation marks and use the YAML map syntax. For example:

```
$ rostopic pub /topic package/msg_type '{x: 1, y: 2, c: a, type: string}'
```

---

Originally posted by [theNerd247](https://answers.ros.org/users/24325/thenerd247/) with karma: 128 on 2015-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shree_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/34279/shree_123/) on 2018-03-23**:
Im trying to publish this exact same msg using unity3d via RosBridge. But its not publishing. When i try publishing in ros ,it works. But doesnt publish using unity(which sends a JSON string)...

PS using ROS Kinetic along with unity 4.6.

**Comment by [Milan](https://answers.ros.org/users/49596/milan/) on 2020-10-06**:
Thanks for the answer. For the command...

```
$ rostopic pub /topic package/msg_type '{x: 1, y: 2, c: a, type: string}'
```

it's worth mentioning that pay close attention to space(s)!!
e.g. `x: 1` will work but `x:1` won't.